# Crontab in Raspberry not working for refreshing website

Tags: midori

This is my short but effective code:

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool search –class midori key F5
```

The code's name is refresh.sh, and I've chmod'ed it. Also, when I run the code from the terminal, it works just as it should. However when I expect `cron` to run it, nothing seems to happen. The code is located on the Raspberries desktop: and this is what the `cron` request looks like:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Desktop/refresh.sh
```

Additionally, I've copied and pasted the above full directory to the terminal, and the code works fine.

I don't know what else to do?

**Question:** How can I make the cron work?

---

**Quickfix:** One quick fix is doing a `while true` loop with a `sleep` function of 60 seconds and just run it, and leave it... but this isn't the *'ethical'* solution. So then the code would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  xdotool search –class midori key F5
  sleep 1m #sleep the code for 1 minute or "sleep 60" can be used as well
done
```

---

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68063